# How to access Arnold python AiNodeSetInt() command in Maya mtoa

Tags: python, maya

Does anyone know how to import this command for the mtoa / Maya plugin. I'm trying things like

from mtoa import *
or
import mtoa.api as mtapi

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: I think what you mean is the arnold api. You can load it by `import arnold` and try `arnold.AiNodeSetInt(...)`.

Comment: import arnold doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: What do you expect should happen if you do `import arnold`?

Comment: Huh- I think that worked. Sorry- I wanst doing it exactly as you said- I was doing "import arnold as..."